# Refactoring the switch statements to polymorphic code

Tags: java, design-patterns, conditional-statements

I have the functionality where my API sends out many types of messages, say, text image video audio and rich media contents. Each of them is sent out differently based on the type of provider (the one who provides a way to send out the messages). The API had the below design,

```
interface Response{
     void sendTextMessage(String message);
     void sendPictureMessage(byte[] image);
     .....
     void sendRichMediaMessage(RichMedia message);
}
```

This API has different implementations for different providers to process and send the message. But the real problem with this approach is, one provider provides new type of message whereas the old providers does not, so they need to implement the new method and throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. So I refactored it like the one below,

```
interface Response {
    void sendMessage(ResponseMessage message);
}
 abstract class ResponseMessage {
    ...
}
public class PlainTextResponse extends ResponseMessage {
   private String message=message;
   public PlainTextResponse(String message) {
      this.message=message;
   }
}
```

Now the client sends the message like,

```
public static void main(String... str) {
    Response resp = ...;
    resp.sendMessage(new PlainTextMessage("Hello World!!!");
}
```

Now implementing a Response interface

```
class ResponseProvider1Impl implement Response {
    public ResponseProvider1Impl(ResponseProcessor processor) {
      this.processor=processor;
    }
    void sendMessage(ResponseMessage message) {
         // how do I get rid of this "if" block
         if(message instanceof PlainTextMessage) {
             processor.sendTextMessage(message.getData());
         } else if(message instanceof PictureMessage) {
              processor.sendPictureMessage(message.getData());
         }
        ......
    }
}
```

I thought the ResponseProcessor would keep many things out from the actual Response interface

```
interface ResponseProcessor  { 
   void sendTextMessage(String message);
     void sendPictureMessage(byte[] image);
     .....
     void sendRichMediaMessage(RichMedia message);
}
```

Things were going good till I got here,

```
class ResponseProcessorProvider1Impl implements ResponseProcessor   {
    void sendTextMessage(String message){// do things to send a text message}
     void sendPictureMessage(byte[] image){}
     .....
     void sendRichMediaMessage(RichMedia message){}
}
```

Now the **question:** How do I get rid of the if blocks that checks and invokes methods based on its type? Yeah, I hear someone saying, move this to a factory with reflection or enum to not use switch or if statements, okay, but is that the right way for this? Do you see a better way to design this? any other design patterns I may apply for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DDMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MsgSender sender = new Provider$ASender();
        Resp resp = new RespImpl(sender);
        resp.sendMsg(new TxtMsg("hello world"));
        resp.sendMsg(new PicMsg(new byte[] { 'p', 'i', 'c' }));
    }
}

interface Resp {

    public void sendMsg(Msg msg);
}

class RespImpl implements Resp {

    private MsgSender sender;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public RespImpl(MsgSender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMsg(Msg msg) {
        msg.sendWith(sender);
    }

}

interface Msg {

    byte[] getMsg();

    void sendWith(MsgSender sender);
}

class TxtMsg implements Msg {

    private String string;

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public TxtMsg(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendWith(MsgSender sender) {
        sender.sendTxtMsg(this);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getMsg() {
        return string.getBytes();
    }
}

class PicMsg implements Msg {

    private byte[] data;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public PicMsg(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendWith(MsgSender sender) {
        sender.sendPictureMsg(this);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see mgage.ott.middleware.newspec.Msg#getMsg()
     */
    @Override
    public byte[] getMsg() {
        return data;
    }
}

interface MsgSender {

    void sendTxtMsg(TxtMsg message);

    void sendPictureMsg(PicMsg rectangle);
}

// this class stays protected and wouldn't be available outside the api.
class Provider$ASender implements MsgSender {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Provider$ASender() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void sendTxtMsg(TxtMsg message) {
        System.out.println("provider-A sending the txt message "
                + new String(message.getMsg()));
    }

    @Override
    public void sendPictureMsg(PicMsg message) {
        System.out.println("provider-A sending the pic message "
                + new String(message.getMsg()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ResponseProcessorProvider1Impl implements ResponseProcessor   {
     .....
     public void sendMessage(ResponseMessage message) {
         // how do I get rid of this "if" blocks
         if(message instanceof PlainTextMessage) {
             sendTextMessage(message.getData());
         } else if(message instanceof PictureMessage) {
              sendTextMessage(message.getData());
         }
     }
      ....
}
```

You are calling the same method to each class, you don't need any switch (if, elseif) condition here, just put directly

```
public void sendMessage(ResponseMessage message) {
         // how do I get rid of this "if" blocks
         sendTextMessage(message.getData());

     }
```

Even in the case you needed to call a different method, I would create a method in each class with the same name which would call the properly method.

If that's the case I would modify *PictureMessage*, *PlainTextMessage*,.. classes adding a new method called **sendMessage**, wich would contain the specific code for each class, or simply the call to the specific method (*sendPictureMessage*, *sendTexMessage*,...)

> class PlainTextMessage->method sendMessage->calls sendTextMessage

so you can keep the interface calling always to sendMessage whatever the class can be.

Comment: Sorry typo, I updated the message now, it is a different method sendPicture(message.getData());

Comment: Can you modify PlainTextMessage and PictureMessage classes? Do you have access to that code?

Comment: Yeah, I can, it is part of my API. Can you brief the modification?

Comment: I've edited the answer, an important advantage of polymorphism is to keep the same nomenclature of their parent methods but with the addition of the possibility of change behavior

Comment: If thats the case then the class hierarchy becomes something like, 
new PlainTextMessage("hello world!!!").sendMessage()... anyway the api should expose these kind of options to the client using this api, right?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned that's the way to use polymorphism instead of the switch statements you were using, but java and classes aren't my natural habitat, this is just what I remember about what I studied. Maybe someone else could help here :-)

Comment: Double dispatch is the pattern to solve this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleDispatchExample

Comment: Yeah, that really made sense. I have added the new sample implementation based on your approach as the answer to this question. thanks Paolo.